# Isolation in Saga patterns

Tags: microservices, isolation-level, saga, acid

I am trying to understand microservices. While going through Saga pattern, I came across this sentence

> Whilst somewhat close to having ACID guarantees, the saga pattern is
> still missing isolation. This means that it is possible to read and
> write data from an incomplete transaction, thus introducing various
> isolation anomalies

I am still not clear on why saga pattern lacks isolation. Can someone please explain with an example.

Answer (score 0):

There's no isolation since the intermediate states are manifested in the services that are part of the saga

when you call another service in a saga it performs the action (e.g. you are buying a ticket,  if you reserve a seat for a show and you're still on the process to pay for the ticket). It isn't isolated as any other interaction with the same service will see the effect of your action (e.g. the specific seat will seem taken for others who are trying to purchase a ticket).

Answer (score 0):

There is total of 6 solutions including:

- Semantic lock
- Commutative update
- Pessimistic view
- Reread value
- Versioning
- By value

you can read more about each of them in this [book](https://microservices.io/book)